# Accordion adjusting height of the panels in jquery 1.10.4

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I know this is well-documented question, but nevertheless - I am stuck.

I am using latest jQuery (1.10.4) and running accordion. The height of panel area now looks like to be set to "auto" because it takes the largest content and applies it to the rest of the panels. According to the API Documentation I have altered the following JS line (heightStyle from "auto" to "content"):

```
$.widget( "ui.accordion", {version: "1.10.4", options: {
    active: 0,
    animate: {},
    collapsible: true,
    event: "click",
    header: "> li > :first-child,> :not(li):even",
    heightStyle: "content",                         <!-- This line is changed -->
    icons: {activeHeader: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s",
        header: "ui-icon-triangle-1-e"},
```

This did not help.
I also tried this (also failed):

```
var heightStyle = $( ".questions" ).accordion("heightStyle");
$( ".questions" ).accordion("heightStyle");
```

And finally I tried this, which surpiringly enough, did not work either:

```
$( "#fullpageaccordion .questions" ).accordion({heightStyle: "content"});
```

(.questions) - is the name for accordion element.

Any ideas? Thanks!

UPDATE 2 - relevant section of html code (Accordion within Tabs):

```
<div class="questions">
<div id="Q401">
<table id="QTable">
<tr>
  <td><div id="QNumber">4.1</div></td>
  <td><div id="QText">Is the vessel provided with adequate operator’s navigation instructions and procedures?</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<div>
<table id="RTable">
<tr>
<td>
<div id="Guidance">
  <p>content</p>
<ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>   
<p></p>
 </div>
 </td>

<td>
<div id="Response" class="Response">
  <label><input type="radio" name="Radio401" value="Y" id="Radio_401Y" onchange='radioChange(this, "401")'>Yes</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="Radio401" value="N" id="Radio_401N" onChange='radioChange(this, "401")'>No</label>
 </div>
 <div id="responseDetails">
    <div id="Observation">
     <label for="observation">Observation:</label>
        <textarea name="observation" id="Obs401" rows="6" disabled style="width: 530px;" placeholder="Enter text of observation here ..."></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="DueDate">
       <label for="DueDate">Due date:<br></label>
       <input name="DueDate" class="DueDate" type="date" id="DueDate401"/>
    </div>
    <div id="actions">
       <label for="actions">Actions required to correct and/or prevent this observation:</label>
       <textarea name="actions" id="pa401" rows="6" style="width: 530px;"></textarea>
     </div>
  </div>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div> //closing class
```

Other questions are the same by structure

Comment: Could you provide some HTML code?

Comment: Great. Can you clarify a bit more what's not behaving like you're expecting? I'm messing around in JSFiddle and I see your accordion panel starts at `4.1 of question` and lasts until after the `Content` radio button. Where do you want it to end?

Comment: Yes, well, I gave only one question and surely the panel will adjust to its size. Suppose you have another question, twice as long, then this first panel will be stretched to accommodate a longer content.

Comment: So I want it to end at the END OF CONTENT of each panel.

Comment: Any luck in JSFiddle?

Comment: My apologies, was preoccupied here with something. It's still not 100% clear to me. You have the `questions` div, which right now contains 1 panel that has a header (text) and the `Content` radio button. You said you wanted it to end at the end content of each panel, with only 1 accordion?

Comment: No, there are about 100 of questions - each of different content size. Surely I only copied one as a structure example.

Comment: I know, that's fine :) What I mean is if you have many questions, and you place them all under the `.questions` div, they will all be inside the accordion scope. So I didn't quite understand how you want to end the accordion scope for each panel. Hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Ok, maybe I am not getting something. Here it is again: There is a question and and user's response (including guidance to users,m comments, radio choices etc). The text of a question goes to the Accordion panel tab while the response content (which has different size) goes to accordion panel area.

Comment: So you want each question to have its own height based on its content. An accordion drapes a certain area for expansion/collapse. You attach an accordion to `.questions`, which is the parent of your many questions. So once you click it, all of them appear/disappear. That's what I understand from the code. Do you expect a different behavior?

Comment: Sorry for the delay; yes, that's correct.

Comment: When I click the accordion tab it opens only response area of that specific question I clicked, because the text of the question is on the panel itself. Other questions are closed/collapsed until you click them. So by default you can only see questions texts themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've messed around quite a bit, and here is a [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nG8AR/3/)

I messed around with your code a little bit, I hope you don't mind :)

Basically I removed the tables and such, so it would fit the structure of the accordion better.
Basically what you need is blocks of questions. Each block has 2 children, an `h3` element  (could be another if you want) and a `div` element.

I gave those blocks a class, and initialized them as such:

`$( ".questionBlock" ).accordion({collapsible: true, active: false });`

This way they start collapsed. Expand each and you can see they each have their own height based on their own content.

Let me know if it's not clear yet.

**EDIT:** Ok I've adjusted it better. This is the initialization:

`$( "#questions" ).accordion({collapsible: true, active: false, autoHeight: false});`

Also, there is no need for the code blocks `questionBlock` anymore. All you need is the `questions` as id, and then follow up with the `<h3>` & `div` combos. I updated the fiddler demo.

**Update:** Add `heightStyle: "content"` to your initialization so you'll have:

`$( ".questions").accordion({collapsible: true, active: false, autoHeight: false, heightStyle: "content"});`

And your fiddle is good to go.

Comment: In my example - QBlock is actually questionBlock, "Q" stands for questions)))))

Comment: @Alexander Yes but your structure didn't work for me. It needs to be a div block containing the header and the body. You separated them to different divs and wrapped them up in tables.

Comment: You would not believe but my original structure was similar to yours but accordion did not work so I had to alter it))))

Comment: Ok, size works excellent - thank you. However, the panel you OPEN would NOT collapse when you OPEN another question. Originally, only ONE panel would remain open. And another thing - why do you have bigHeight only assigned for question 2 and not for 1?

Comment: @Alexander Hmm it's weird, I can't reproduce what you're saying. I can expand/collapse each question independently. The `bigHeight` is there only on `Question 2` to demonstrate that even though `Question 2` is bigger (100px height), `Question 1` remains smaller in size, depending only on its content.

Comment: @Alexander Notice `Question 2` is a bit slower on that animation for some reason, so if you're clicking it give it a second.

Comment: Yeh, bigHeight is ok - I am more concerned with accordion NOT AUTOCOLLAPSING when you click on the next panel, thus the previous should COLLAPSE.

Comment: I can also expand and collapse each question but there should be only ONE question OPEN at a time. This is a default behavior of accordion in jQuery.

Comment: @Alexander Oh I see what you mean. I'll try to fix it

Comment: Nope - I am back to where I was ((((((((

Comment: @Alexander I'd be happy to try and help more if you want. Let me know what doesn't work

Comment: Thank you! I will post two of my first questions "as they are" with all elements they contain. I believe the problem is in structure.

Comment: Updated the html code in the original question window. This is the first question, second and others are of the same structure. So now it behaves as before - accordion open and collapses as designed but AutiHeight option does NOT work, being adjusted by its largest content size.

Comment: @Alexander Is it possible for you to create a fiddle demo of this? I'll have a look tomorrow morning

Comment: YES!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! It WORKS!!!!!!!! Thank you! I though I would have brain seizure!

Comment: @Alexander Glad we saved you from a seizure :)